# iOS pushViewController not navigating to controller in Swift5

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am having issues using pushViewController in Swift5, I have searched StackOverflow for answers & could not find any one that works.

All I'm trying to do is navigate to another controller using pushViewController.

Using self.present works for Navigation but pushViewController does not work, for reasons I do not know.

ONLY Using present works below:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = 
    storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But using pushViewController never works:

I tried this: I doesn't work

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

I tried this: I doesn't work too

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController" )
var navigationController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

I tried this, It also doesn't work

```
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController" )
let vc = self.windowRootViewController() as! ViewController
let nvc = vc.parent as! UINavigationController
nvc.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Please can someone guide me properly on what I'm doing wrong or checklist or configuration I need to do for this to work?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Where do you call this code?  Is this in a view controller which is in a navigation controller? It seems like you don't have a navigation controller as a parent.

Comment: Yes, the ViewController which I am navigating to has a navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

Set breakpoint in your code and check whether `navigationController` is not nil. If it is nil, `pushViewController` will not work.

Since you are able to present the viewController, instantiating itt using "`ViewController`" should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewController` which try to push must be embedded into `NavigationController`.

Assume you have two ViewControllers - `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB`. 
In order to push `ViewControllerB` from `ViewControllerA`, The `ViewControllerA` must be **embedded** into `NavigationController`. 
So that you can push `ViewControllerB` to the navigation stack.

If `ViewControllerA` is not embedded into `NavigationController` It's *navigationController* property will be *nil*. So you will not be able to push `ViewControllerB`.